# How to implement a case statement if there's a single digit for a particular day in the year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have this piece of code:

```
select convert(varchar(5),datepart(dd,max(getdate())))
```

Which produces this result:

```
 Output: 5
```

So today is August 5, 2015. For example: the Day should have a 0 before the day if single digits. Example: if the date is June 4, 2015 it should display: 04 Day of June 2015.

How can I do this?

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? You should only use one tag or the other.

Comment: SQL Server is what I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for month as well

```
RIGHT('00' + datename(dd,max(getdate())), 2)
```

Comment: I would advise using `datename()` rather than `datepart()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the tip. Updated answer to get rid of `CONVERT`

Answer (score 1):

please try this in MS SQL

```
select RIGHT('0' + convert(varchar(5),datepart(dd,max(getdate()))), 2);
```

OR

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEPART(dd,getdate()),'00')
```

OR

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(20), GETDATE(),103), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do this way also

```
select REPLACE(STR(convert(varchar(5),datepart(dd,max(getdate()))),2),' ','0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) As varchar), 2) + ' Day of '
 + DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS varchar)
```